# Can I transfer the data from my Wii to my new Wii U without erasing the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

The Wii U can transfer data from an older Wii using a new channel called the "Wii U Transfer Tool" which Nintendo has made available. However, the instructions state that **once the data is transferred off the Wii to the Wii U, the data is permanently deleted from the Wii** and cannot be restored. According to the Wii U Manual:

> **IMPORTANT: Transferred data is permanently deleted from the Wii Console. Once you have Transferd data to the Wii U Console, it cannot be transferred back to a Wii console. Data cannot be transferred from your Wii U console to a Wii console.**

I just tried copying all my Miis to a Wiimote, but on the Wii U, There is no way to copy Wiis from a Wii Remote back to the Wii U... so that plan failed...

Is there any way to transfer the data from an older Wii console to a new Wii U *without* deleting the data off the old Wii? I don't trust the new Wii U to be 100% backwards compatible and I might still want to use the Wii!

Comment: If your Wii has the homebrew channel(hacks!!!) then you can probably make a NAND backup and restore it after the transfer.

Comment: @Mr.November I do have the homebrew channel. I should have tried that!

Comment: @Mr.November: technically, you need nootmii for this, not HBC, but I'm not sure you can get an HBC installer that doesn't also offer to install bootmii, so I guess that's no very important.  Also, I hear that visiting the Shop Channel after restoring NAND will delete everything again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any way to transfer the data from my old Wii to the new Wii U without running the Wii U Transfer Tool. I tried copying all my Miis to a Wii Remote but the new Mii editor under the Wii System Menu on the new Wii U doesn't offer a way to transfer to/from Wii Remotes. As expected, the Wii U Transfer Tool deleted all data off the old Wii.

**However**, I found a kludgy workaround: Before using the Wii U Transfer Tool, I had copied all my Miis to a Wii Remote, and I copied all my save game data to a *different* SD card first. It was a major pain, but it **did** allow me to keep a backup copy and restore the Miis to the old Wii after using the Wii U Transfer Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but if you soft-modded your wii and have the Homebrew Channel installed, you can backup all of your Miis/Saves using this wii channel,
http://wiibrew.org/wiki/SaveGame_Manager_GX
Works great!

Comment: That would have saved me a bit of time! However, since asking this, I've stayed with the new Wii U 100% and haven't looked back once.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's part of their DRM strategy to limit copying, so you can't keep copies of your stuff (especially downloaded games) on the old console. As such there's no built in way to Keep things (although I feel this is odd, especially for things like Miis or savegames).

If you want to keep stuff, you have to create backups first and use these to get things back. The transfer itself obviously requires a SD Card, even if you've got other possibilities working in other situations (like the controller transfer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 3DS?  Transfer your Miis from your Wii to your Wii U via your 3DS.  It works like a charm.

As for other data, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Mii to Wii U transfer**, While it is not possible to use the wii remotes to transfer Mii's to a Wii U, it is possible to transfer Mii's from your Wii to a 3DS. It is also possible to then transfer from the 3DS to your Wii U.